# Can we compare probabilities of two independent events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kxnPEDecIA) that is often used to illustrate PMF of exponential and memorylessness property:
we calculate probability of a failure of two identical lightbulbs, one is new and the other is a used one. And, apparently, expected time until failure is the same for both and when we compare the two it raises questions, since it is counterintuitive: [Exponential bulbs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478820/exponential-bulbs/3620122#3620122)

My question is: How can we compare probabilities of two different lightbulbs? I was thinking the sample space of new light bulb and an old one are different (identical but different), and probability is a relative thing, and can only be viewd within its own sample space. So we can only compare probability of a failure of the same lightbulb and not two different lightbulbs. So the PMF would be the same, but we couldn't compare them since they are two different events. So, an old lightbulb is more likely to burn out in a year than in a month, but it gives us no information how it compares to a new lightbulb, those are two independent events. Am I wrong?

Comment: By two different lightbulbs, do you mean lightbulbs coming from two different factories (so different PMF), or simply two lightbulbs, which may or may not come from the same factory (so could have the same PMF)?

Comment: Completely identical lightbulbs with Identical PMFs

Answer (score 1):

Lets say I have two identical coins with probability of getting Heads 1/1,000,000.

Now, I take one coin, toss it 100 times, and get Tails every time.

Now, question is has the probability of getting Heads changed for this coin?

No. It's still 1/1,000,000. Coins are still the same.

Maybe probability of lightbulbs' failure could be different due to assembling process and used materials. But we still could compare them, and until you are hundred percent sure that **there are** some limit of working Time - expected lifetime will have exponential distribution.

Comment: So, if lifetime expectancy diminishes due to wearing out, then expected lifetime of a new lightbulb will be longer then a used one. If the lifetime expectancy diminishes due to a random event, then they will be the same, right?

Comment: @Ilya, I agree with your comment. This seems to be my understanding of your linked article, too. Perhaps you can clarify your question? As I don't really understand what is different between your question and your linked quesiton.

Comment: @Ilya if there are  life expectancy are somehow connected  with time then yes. But in given example they are not.